# line breaks </br> not recognised on a 4.3 simulator. its OK using 5.1 simulator

Tags: cordova, ios4, ios-simulator

I built a Phonegap app using 5.1 SDK. When running my app using 5.1 simulator, LINE BREAKS are recognised. But for some reason, when running my app on a 4.3 simulator, it doesnt work.

*(phonegap version 1.9, jqm 1.1, jquery 1.7)*

```
formatedAdd = "Current location:  </br >" + results[0].formatted_address;
```

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linebreak is `<br />` and not `</br >`. It may have worked on 5.1 because of quirks mode(?)

Comment: i cant tell who was the first person to answer.... so i put the tick next to you, Calavoow. Please tel me if its wrong

Comment: @AbdulHasan: Calavoow answered 18 seconds before me, so you did right, even if it hurts :) (If you hoover the mouse over the text "X hours ago", you will see the exact timestamp of the post)

Answer (score 3):

The correct HTML linebreak tag is `<br />`, not `</br>`.

So, you probably just want to change the line to

```
formatedAdd = "Current location:  <br />" + results[0].formatted_address;
```

Comment: LMAO, you know when your so into the code that you forget the basics! thanks for showing me and iv now uploaded my app for review :-)